# How can I add From date to To date to print a set of records in report in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, report, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am creating  a Bank module, where the customers can buy loans from the bank. In that I want to print a report statement. Before printing the records of a particular customer, i want to filter the dates. I want to filter it by giving From date to To date. So the loan amounts where the customer bought from the bank in that given dates should print.

Thank You,

Hope I will gain some knowledge.

Comment: you asking which xls or pdf report?

Comment: i think you ask ingthis kind of method [https://i.imgur.com/wrpNsN7.png]

Comment: pdf report, and yes, I want it like in that image @KLN

Comment: you have create wizard and with that wizard have you required files and buttons, in that button you have write pdf template calling and send data   to pdf_report

Comment: i have created the wizard and all. I just want to know how to filter the records using the dates. The python coding and the report xml coding may help me if you send me

Answer (score 2):

below code for wizard

```
class BankCustomer(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'bank.customer'
    _description = 'Bank Customer Report'


    date_from = fields.Date(string='From date', required=True,default=lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))
    date_to = fields.Date(string='To date', required=True,default=lambda *a: str(datetime.now() + relativedelta.relativedelta(months=+1, day=1, days=-1))[:10])


@api.multi
def pdf_bank_customer_report(self):
    data = self.read()[0]
    datas = {
        'ids': [],
        'model': 'bank.customer',
        'form': data
    }
    return self.env['report'].with_context(landscape=True).get_action(self, 'module_name.template_name', data=datas)    




class BankCustomerReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.module_name.template_name



def get(self):
    self.env.cr.execute(""" you query """+ datas['date_from'],datas['date_to'] ))

    line_list = [i for i in self.env.cr.dictfetchall()]
    finallist = [] 

    import datetime
    for fin in line_list:
        #sale_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(fin['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%m-%y')
        finallist.append({
            'date': fin['date'],
 'here gat  you requirened field from query'
        })
       finally pass thislist to report template

    return finallist

@api.model
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    Report = self.env['report']
    sale_report = Report._get_report_from_name('module_name.report_template_name')
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    active_ids = context.get('active_ids', [])
    register = self.env['bank.customer'].browse(active_ids)
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': sale_report.model,
        'docs': register,
        'details':self.get_det,

    }
    return Report.render('module_name.report_template_name', docargs)
```